# Converting all H5 to H3 in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to find a way to convert all the H5 tags in hundreds of posts to a H3 tag instead. Is there a smart way to do that?

I appreciate any help a lot!

Comment: Are they inside the text content? or in a template?

Comment: If in post content, another option is to use a find & replace plugin and replace them all at a DB level for the `wp_posts` table

Comment: I have used FInd & Replace plugin myself and found it to be great. Just remember to backup your database before doing this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your server's panel (usually Cpanel, Plesk panel etc.),you can reach to your website's files and in that panel you can use find&replace setting of the panel. If you do not have access to your site files, you can use this [extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sheet-editor-bulk-spreadsheet-editor-for-posts-and-pages/).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it using jQuery very quickly. you need to place your class name in place of ".classname" in below jQuery

```
$('.classname h5').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<h3>', {
        'class': this.className,
        'html':  this.innerHTML
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need a classname? I am not sure what that classname could be? Right now I think they are just called H5...?